# Python Scraping Website urls and article numbers

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Actually I want to scrape the all-child product link of these websites with the child product.

Website which I am scraping is : https://lappkorea.lappgroup.com/

My work code is :

```
  from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://lappkorea.lappgroup.com/product-introduction/online-catalogue/power-and-control-cables/various-applications/pvc-outer-sheath-and-coloured-cores/oelflex-classic-100-300500-v.html')

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('span[contains(.//table[contains(@class, "setuArticles") and not(@data-search)]//td/div/@data-content')

urls = []


content = driver.page_source
tree = html.fromstring(content)

all_links = tree.xpath('.//a/@href')

first_link = all_links[0]

for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
    urls.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
for elem in elems:
        writer.write(f"{elem.get_attribute('href')}, {elem.text}\n")

writer.close()

driver.quit()
```

This is the data which I want to scrape from the whole website :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RS34.png)

When we go to any product as for the one product link is mentioned on the code. We drag down and click on the any article number and popup datasheet appers, click on it pdf will open.

I just want that Artciles numbers with their PDF links.

I have a CSV of the all parent links which I scraped, as I give one link in the script i.e: "https://lappkorea.lappgroup.com/product-introduction/online-catalogue/power-and-control-cables/various-applications/pvc-outer-sheath-and-coloured-cores/oelflex-classic-100-300500-v.html". I want to get all the links from that CSV file which I have and scraped the all products article number and Child Product links as you did above and want to save them in one CSV file in separate columns one column is for the article number and one is for the child product links

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html


rows = open("products.csv", 'r').read().split('\n')
writer = open('zain details.csv', 'w')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.split(',')

    url = cols[0]

    response = requests.get(url)
    print(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        tree = html.fromstring(response.content)



# url = "https://lappkorea.lappgroup.com/product-introduction/online-catalogue/power-and-control-cables/various-applications/pvc-outer-sheath-and-coloured-cores/oelflex-classic-100-300500-v.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for article in soup.select('[id*="-article-"] [data-content]'):
    s = BeautifulSoup(article["data-content"], "html.parser")
    link = s.select_one("a:-soup-contains(Datasheet)")["href"]
    num = article.get_text(strip=True)
    print("{:<10} {}".format(num, link))

    record = f"{cols[0]}, {cols[1]}, {an}\n"

    writer.write(record)
```

Image of the CSV file :

[image]

Error while running on the server

[image]

Help me get out of this to run on the server

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find the [product list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RS34.png) within the [url](https://lappkorea.lappgroup.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scrapy spider that does what you want.

steps to reproduce:

1. install scrapy `pip install scrapy`
2. start project `scrapy startproject lappkorea`
3. `cd lappkorea`
4. open new file in `./lappkorea/spiders` and copy and paste the following code
5. #### here **->** `scrapy crawl lappkorea -o "zain details.csv"`  **<- this is your output file**

```py
import scrapy
import lxml.html as lhtml

class LappkoreaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lappkorea'
    allowed_domains = ['lappgroup.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('products.csv') as file:   # <- url file
            for line in file:
                cols = line.split(',')
                url = cols[0]
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//tr[@class="article"]'):
            div = row.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"pointer jsLoadPopOver")]')
            idnum = div.xpath('./text()').get()
            html = div.xpath('./@data-content').get()
            tree = lhtml.fromstring(html)
            link = tree.xpath("//ul/li/a/@href")[0]
            yield {
                "id": idnum.strip(),
                "link": response.urljoin(link)
            }
```

---

Update

If you wanted to run the spider as a script instead of using the command line you could do this instead.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import lxml.html as lhtml

class LappkoreaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lappkorea'
    allowed_domains = ['lappgroup.com']

    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'filename.csv': {   # <---- this will be the output file
#         -------------------
                'format': 'csv',
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'store_empty': False,
                'fields': ['id', 'link']
             }
         }
    }


    def start_requests(self):
        with open('products.csv') as file:   # <- url file
            for line in file:
                cols = line.split(',')
                url = cols[0]
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//tr[@class="article"]'):
            div = row.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"pointer jsLoadPopOver")]')
            idnum = div.xpath('./text()').get()
            html = div.xpath('./@data-content').get()
            tree = lhtml.fromstring(html)
            link = tree.xpath("//ul/li/a/@href")[0]
            yield {
                "id": idnum.strip(),
                "link": response.urljoin(link)
            }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(LappkoreaSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Its working but It duplicates the csv data. and I am also wanto to get the URLs from my csv files and scrape them the same data and make one csv file

Comment: I have mutiples URls in the csv files. I read all of them and scraped the same data for all  and saves in a one csv. You can go to that website

Comment: Can you please add to the above code. I can't understand. Help me to get out of this. I am stuck here

Comment: kindly check tihis. I have no add any header for the csv. Image is add in the question

Comment: Cab you please confirm where I need to put my URLs csv and the second CSV which will be create.

Comment: Okay. Can you please confirm what will be the name of the file which will generate.

Comment: I think its created in the same File.

Comment: It works like expected. One more thing you can help me that If I want to create a new csv for this

Comment: @RanaZain  If thats all please remember to mark the question as answered

Comment: When I run on the server it shows this error : add in the post

Comment: Just please tell me one last thing Can I run this command  scrapy crawl lappkorea -o newfilename.csv in the spider directory only or run it from any where. Actually I have a bash script for mutiple python scripts. I run all scripts by one bash script

Comment: This is the correct way I am using this ssh from my home directory                     
 python3 /home/vendor/python_script/scrape_category_urls.py &
python3 /home/vendor/python_script/scrape_products_urls.py &
scrapy crawl lappkorea -o shd.csv /home/vendor/python_script/lappkorea/lappkorea/spiders/childnew.py

Comment: On running this got this errror     'encoding': 'utf8',
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  And how I can get the data from the URLs to scrape.

Comment: Sorry I forgot a comma.   try it now @RanaZain .  Using it this way is the exact same as the other way except you specify the output filename inside the code where I commented instead of specifying it on the command line

Comment: Now this is the issue :NameError: name 'CrawlerProcess' is not defined

Comment: Why did you add car spider at the end

Comment: It works. But As I am getting the URL from the scripts file so what for the new file I want to craete as I used the new file name in this command before  scrapy crawl lappkorea -o "zain details.csv"

Comment: I underlined it in the code @RanaZain

Comment: Can you share the code I want to compare two similar CSV files with almost same data and create third CSV file that returns the difference between them

Comment: Both of these files have no any headers

Comment: right with csv you need to add the headers to the FEEDS dictionary i added it for you  here is a link to the documentation   https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html  @RanaZain

Comment: @RanaZain  Was there anything else you needed help with?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://lappkorea.lappgroup.com/product-introduction/online-catalogue/power-and-control-cables/various-applications/pvc-outer-sheath-and-coloured-cores/oelflex-classic-100-300500-v.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for article in soup.select('[id*="-article-"] [data-content]'):
    s = BeautifulSoup(article["data-content"], "html.parser")
    link = s.select_one("a:-soup-contains(Datasheet)")["href"]
    num = article.get_text(strip=True)
    print("{:<10} {}".format(num, link))
```

Prints:

```
...

1120824    /fileadmin/documents/technische_doku/datenblaetter/oelflex/DB00100004EN.pdf
1120825    /fileadmin/documents/technische_doku/datenblaetter/oelflex/DB00100004EN.pdf
1120826    /fileadmin/documents/technische_doku/datenblaetter/oelflex/DB00100004EN.pdf
1120827    /fileadmin/documents/technische_doku/datenblaetter/oelflex/DB00100004EN.pdf
1120828    /fileadmin/documents/technische_doku/datenblaetter/oelflex/DB00100004EN.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like charm. I have a CSV of the all parent links which I scraped, as I give one link in the script i.e: "https://lappkorea.lappgroup.com/product-introduction/online-catalogue/power-and-control-cables/various-applications/pvc-outer-sheath-and-coloured-cores/oelflex-classic-100-300500-v.html". I want to get all the links from that CSV file which I have and scraped the all products article number and Child Product links as you did above and want to save them in one CSV file in separate columns one column is for the article number and one is for the child product links.

Comment: @RanaZain Just create a function that returns necessary information (instead of print I have in my script). Then open your csv, call that function for every row you have and save new csv.

Comment: Okay @AndrejKesely. I did this but it doesn't work. I have attached the script in the question.